# How to throw an error without throw

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

So recently I was asked a *question* :

### Is there a way to throw an error without using `throw` in javaScript ?

As far as I knew about errors, there was only one way to throw an error in JavaScript and that was using `throw` statement in JavaScript like so :

```js
var myFunc = () => {
  // some code here 
  throw 'Some error' // in a conditional 
  // some more code
}

try {
  myFunc()
}catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

And not knowing any other way I said `No, there is no other way`. But now I'm wondering whether I was right ?

So the question is whether or not you can throw a **custom** error in JavaScript without using `throw`

---

## Restrictions :

- Kindly no using `eval` , `Function`.
- Don't use `throw` in your code

---

## Additional :

If you can throw an error without using the word `Error`

Comment: Does constructing the string "throw" and using e.g. `eval` count?

Comment: @ASDFGerte : No eval kindly

Comment: Did the question include the ability to, for example, divide by zero?

Comment: @slash_rick_dot : No division by zero (the question forbade me from division completely)

Comment: Codewars, amirite? :D

Comment: With Node, how about simply call `process.exit()`

Answer (score 5):

Generators do have a `throw` method that is usually used to throw an exception into the generator function code (at the place of a `yield` expression, similar to `next`), but if not caught it bubbles out of the call:

```
(function*(){})().throw(new Error("example"))
```

Of course, this is a hack and not good style, I have no idea what answer they expected. Especially the "no division by zero" requirement is sketchy, since division by zero does not throw exceptions in JS anyway.

Comment: @Konowy Just curious though, do you have a real-world use case or is there just a popular quiz about this?

Comment: No. I just used this code for this kata https://www.codewars.com/kata/5970f479e75b6c00ce000043

I don't believe that there would be a real-world example.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function throwErrorWithoutThrow(msg) {
  // get sample error 
  try {
    NaN();
  } catch (typeError) {
    // aquire reference to Error
    let E = typeError.__proto__.__proto__.constructor;

    // prepare custom Error
    let error = E(msg);

    // throw custom Error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}

throwErrorWithoutThrow("hi")
  /* catch the error, you have to use .catch as this is a promise
  that's the only drawback, you can't use try-catch to catch these errors */
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("Caught You!");
    console.error(e);
  });
```

Comment: You could wrap this in a function myCustomErr(message) and scope E, IMHO best answer for getting the constructor from another Error.

Comment: Good idea, see the update (only wrapped it in a function though), I also added a comment on how to catch these errors.

Comment: This is the drawback of promises, and as nobody thought a try{}catch{} friendly solution, I posted my own.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is throw an error then just do an invalid operation. I've listed a few below. Run them on your browser console to see the errors (tested on chrome and firefox).

```js
var myFunc = () => {
  encodeURI('\uD800');    // URIError
  a = l;                  // ReferenceError
  null.f()                // TypeError
}


try {
  myFunc()
}catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: `So the question is whether or not you can throw an error in JavaScript without using throw`. No where does it say anything about a custom error. Please update the question

Comment: I like this answer for its sneakiness.  The question is interesting in the abstract sense, but I want to ask "When an error occurs, what kind of situation could require us to avoid throwing errors?"  Ideally, erroneous code should be spotted and fixed, so programming errors don't seem to apply here, but input or streaming errors for example might need to be identified, handled and addressed while the application continues - and this is where something like this might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you want to use `try...catch` blocks, you will need to throw something to get to the `catch`part. You can use pretty much everything that fails with an error to do that (like mentioned in the other posts).

If at some point, you want to *run-or-die* without having to write the throw statement yourself, you can always do an assertion:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  try {
    assert.fail();
    console.log(`Did not work :)`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`OK`);
  }
};
```

Of course I would rather try to assert something positive (more Zen), that I need in order to continue.

Answer (score 1):

```
const myTypeErr = () => `This is a Custom Err Message... \nand it`()

try {
  myTypeErr()
} catch(e) {} // caught

myTypeErr() // Uncaught TypeError: "This is a Custom Err Message... 
              // and it" is not a function
```